# what is the limit of account create in an organisation?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake How many account one can create in an organization. I read a soft limit is 25 how far we can go in this count.
Is there any good practice of creating a separate account of the client rather than creating a different DB in an account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the maximum number of accounts in an organization cannot exceed 25.

This can be increased by contacting Snowflake Support.